# SQL error with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE id LIKE %1%
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%1%' at line 1
```

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `orders` ";

switch ($_POST['criteria']) {

    case 'id':
        $sql .= "WHERE id LIKE %" . (int) $_POST['search_input'] . "%";
    break;
    case 'OCR':
        $sql .= "WHERE OCR LIKE %" . $db->quote($_POST['search_input']) . "%";
    break;
    case 'name':
        $arr = explode(' ', $_POST['search_input']);
        $firstname = $arr[0];

        if (isset($arr[1])) {
            $lastname = $arr[1];
        } else {
            $lastname = null;
        }

        $sql .= "WHERE firstname LIKE %" . $db->quote($firstname) . "% AND lastname LIKE %" . $db->quote($lastname) . "%";
    break;
}

echo $sql;

$stmt = $db->query($sql);

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The query is being outputted and it looks fine to me, but for some reason I am getting a syntax error ( I assume it is), however I can't seem to spot any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly  write  pattern in  single qoute ''   and like me sure

```
         incorrect     SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE id LIKE %1%
           correct-     SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE id LIKE '%1%'
```

Answer (score 3):

[LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator is a string function. So you need to enclose it with single quotes(').

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE id LIKE '%1%';
```

Answer (score 3):

You have quotes missing around your strings, so your quesries look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM orders where id LIKE %55%
```

instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM orders where id LIKE '%55%'


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `orders` ";

switch ($_POST['criteria']) {

    case 'id':
        $sql .= "WHERE id LIKE '%" . (int) $_POST['search_input'] . "%'";
    break;
    case 'OCR':
        $sql .= "WHERE OCR LIKE '%" . $db->quote($_POST['search_input']) . "%'";
    break;
    case 'name':
        $arr = explode(' ', $_POST['search_input']);
        $firstname = $arr[0];

        if (isset($arr[1])) {
            $lastname = $arr[1];
        } else {
            $lastname = null;
        }

        $sql .= "WHERE firstname LIKE '%" . $db->quote($firstname) . "% AND lastname LIKE '%" . $db->quote($lastname) . "%'";
    break;
}

echo $sql;

$stmt = $db->query($sql);

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This answer should fix your problem but I strongly suggest you use `=` instead of `LIKE` since you are looking for unique orders identified by `id`.

Yhe way you script is currently written, if `id` is 55, you will get orders 55, 255, 5500, 1559...

Comment: That worked for ID, but on OCR the SQL outputted is: SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE OCR LIKE '%'1000'%'

which gives me Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1000'%'' at line 1'

Comment: @user2141625 As you can see from the error message, you probably have `.. LIKE '%'"`. Remove apostrophe from inside the string.

Comment: Well, that's because of $db->quote (PDO) I assume, however, that would cause a SQL Injection problem?

Comment: You already have an injection problem. PDO doesn't help if you're building the query string by hand.

Comment: Then you would do `$sql .= "WHERE OCR LIKE " . $db->quote('%'.$_POST['search_input'].'%');`

Comment: Well, If I try use prepared statements, then It's giving me no result, but no errors either

  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE OCR LIKE :ocr");

  $OCR = "'%" . $_POST['search_input'] . "%'";

  $stmt->bindParam(':ocr', $OCR);